# Find a basis for ker(T) and range(T) for the given transformation and compute T(5x-4)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

[image: Full problem]

I am not really having trouble with $a)$, $c)$, $d)$ or $e)$.

For $a)$ I put that $B$ is a basis for $\mathbb{P}^1$ because it has ${\rm dim} = 2$ and the highest degree is 1, and for $B'$ it has ${\rm dim} = 3$ and highest degree 2.

For $b)$ I thought to put $T(5x-4)= c_1(1-x)+c_2(1+x)$ for which I get $c_1=-\frac{9}{2}$ and $c_2=\frac{1}{2}$, which I would then use as a $2 \times 1$ matrix to multiply $\lbrack T \rbrack_{B,B'}$ by.however I also have $B'$ so I don't know what to do with that, do I put $T(5x-4)=c_1(1)+c_2(1-x)+c_3(1+x^2)$?

For $c)$ I'm pretty sure I need part $b)$

For $d)$ i know that $T$ is not onto because $\mathbb{P}^1 < \mathbb{P}^2$. Not sure about 1 to 1

I am pretty sure $e)$ will be obvious once I have the ker and range.

Right now I am mostly stuck on $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, applying matrix $\lbrack T \rbrack_{B, B'}$ to the expansion of $5x-4$ in basis $B$ gives you an expansion of result in basis $B'$. So, to compute the final result you have to "convert" the expansion in basis $B'$ to the usual polynomial by forming linear combination of $B'$ basis polys with coefficients from $B'$-expansion vector.

Comment: I think I got it. After getting c1 and c2 as I mentioned above, I multiplied the given matrix to get <-23,115/2,-69/2> which I then used to transform B' into a poly by -23(1)+115/2(1-x)-69/2(1+x^2). The constants cancelled out and I simplified my answer to get 2(-115x-69x^2). Does that sound about right?

Comment: Yes, you've got it right, but there is a typo in last formula: it must be $0.5 (-115x - 69x^2)$. Also, use $\LaTeX$ for writing formulas.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yeah I meant to put 1/2 not 2. Also what is LATEX? I am pretty new here and don't know much about formatting.

Comment: This is a kind of notation for math symbols and formulas. You may want to take a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for better formatting of your questions.